# Can't figure out what this matrix datatype module means, need to display its contents

Tags: haskell, matrix

Alright, so I'm supposed to create a show method for a matrix module, in order to display matrix row by row. Now they've given me a module to start with, but I have no clue what it means, and the person who sent it didn't really explain it. I'm new to Haskell, and I've also never programmed with a functional language before. If anyone can give my some clarification as to how this module works, I'd appreciate it.

Here's the matrix module I'm supposed to work with:

```
module Matrix (Matrix, fillWith, fromRule, numRows, numColumns, at, mtranspose, mmap) where
newtype Matrix a = Mat ((Int,Int), (Int,Int) -> a)

fillWith :: (Int,Int) -> a -> (Matrix a)
fillWith (n,m) k = Mat ((n,m), (\(_,_) -> k))

fromRule :: (Int,Int) -> ((Int,Int) -> a) -> (Matrix a)
fromRule (n,m) f = Mat ((n,m), f)

numRows :: (Matrix a) -> Int
numRows (Mat ((n,_),_)) = n

numColumns :: (Matrix a) -> Int
numColumns (Mat ((_,m),_)) = m

at :: (Matrix a) -> (Int, Int) -> a
at (Mat ((n,m), f)) (i,j)| (i > 0) && (j > 0) || (i <= n) && (j <= m) = f (i,j)

mtranspose :: (Matrix a) -> (Matrix a)
mtranspose (Mat ((n,m),f)) = (Mat ((m,n),\(j,i) -> f (i,j)))

mmap :: (a -> b) -> (Matrix a) -> (Matrix b)
mmap h (Mat ((n,m),f)) = (Mat ((n,m), h.f))
```

Now I think, but I don't know about this, that the fillWith functions creates the matrix, however. I'm also thinking that `Mat ((Int,Int,), (Int,Int) -> a` takes a pair of values, most likely number of rows and columns. I'm not sure what the second pair of values is or what the a does. I'm also not sure about what this does `fillWith (n,m) k = Mat ((n,m), (\(_,_) -> k))` except for the fact that it is saying that fillWith's result is equal to the Mat constructor, but then whats `(\(_,_) -> k))` this for. All I know is that the lambda is to define an anonymuous function, but why are those spaces empty, and why is k being referenced as the function. I really want to learn haskell, if anyone also knows of any tutorials I'd appreciate it.

Basically, if I find out what Matrix is composed of, I can figure out a way to print its contents. I'm assuming Matrix is basically a multidimensional array, but I really have no way of knowing to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Matrix` consists of a size, and a function that takes a coordinate and returns the value at that coordinate.

Presumably `fillWith` creates a matrix where *all* the elements are the same. That's why the lambda function ignores the coordinates (that's what the underscores are for) and always returns `k` (the value that the array is going filled with).

You can see that the `at` function returns the element at a given pair of coordinates. (But it checks the coordinates are valid first.) By constructing a loop that calls `at` to get each element, you should be able to print out the matrix contents.

Comment: Interesting, I was planning to use numRows to do something else, but I figure as I'm new its probably better to do that in order to understand what's really going on and then do something more comolex. From what I saw in other matrix implementations, they're basically collections of vectors. I wonder if this one is too.